# where should brackets be placed in join statement?

Tags: sql, join

Executing this statement:

```
select  Item.ItemId, 
        ProductGroup.ProductGroupId,
        ItemUom.ContentQty
from Item
join ItemUom on ItemUom.Item = Item.Oid where ItemUomId = 'Stuks'
join ProductGroup on Item.ProductGroup = ProductGroup.Oid
```

gives this error :

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'join'.

When I reverse the 2 join statements it works. I guess I should place somewhere some brackets in the first join statement, but where?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can solve this problem in two ways 
1. without where clause

```
select  Item.ItemId, 
                ProductGroup.ProductGroupId,
                ItemUom.ContentQty
        from Item
        join ItemUom on ItemUom.Item = Item.Oid and ItemUomId = 'Stuks' /*where ItemUomId = 'Stuks'*/
        join ProductGroup on Item.ProductGroup = ProductGroup.Oid
```

2. Using where clause

```
     select  Item.ItemId, 
                        ProductGroup.ProductGroupId,
                        ItemUom.ContentQty
                from Item
                join ItemUom on ItemUom.Item = Item.Oid
                join ProductGroup on Item.ProductGroup = ProductGroup.Oid
                where ItemUomId = 'Stuks'
```

Where clause should be added at end of the query, excluding the case when we are using subquery.

Answer (score 1):

`where` should go after `join`s :

```
select Item.ItemId, ProductGroup.ProductGroupId, ItemUom.ContentQty
from Item join 
     ItemUom 
     on ItemUom.Item = Item.Oid join 
     ProductGroup 
     on Item.ProductGroup = ProductGroup.Oid
where ItemUomId = 'Stuks';
```

You can also add `AND` with `JOIN` :

```
on ItemUom.Item = Item.Oid and ItemUomId = 'Stuks'
```

However, `where` after `join`s are more readable.

Note : Be careful while using `where` clause from `left` table while using `left join`, it will force outer join to inner join.

Answer (score 0):

It works when you reverse them because reversing them puts the WHERE in the right place:

```
select  Item.ItemId, 
        ProductGroup.ProductGroupId,
        ItemUom.ContentQty
from Item
join ItemUom on ItemUom.Item = Item.Oid --where ItemUomId = 'Stuks'
join ProductGroup on Item.ProductGroup = ProductGroup.Oid

where ItemUomId = 'Stuks'
```